# RESTful API and calling remote methods (RPC)

Tags: rest, web, architecture

So i'm doing a bit of research on RESTful APIs and i'm trying to get some clarification on how to call methods on resources (essentially RPC).

So if I wanted to call a method (cancel) on a resource (an order), from what I can see so far I can do it one of two ways:

```
POST /api/1/orders/123/cancel { }
```

or

```
POST /api/1/orders/123 { 'action' : 'cancel' }
```

Hopefully that makes sense?

Personally I like the former more, you can just type out the url and call the method, the later requires a little extra work with POST params. Any params required by the method would go inside the POST?

I guess a 3rd is by doing:

```
PATCH /api/1/orders/123 { 'state' : 'cancelled' }
```

But I'm trying to keep an order's (object's) fields and methods separate.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is number four, PATCH the order setting the status field of the *resource* to 'cancel'

```
PATCH /api/1/orders/123 { 'status' : 'cancel' }
```

or maybe

```
PUT /api/1/orders/123/status cancel
```

The latter has the advantage of being very easy to link to and use with a html form.

Comment: But 'cancel' is a verb (a method), 'cancelled' is the appropriate state. So, calling 'cancel' changes the 'state' to 'cancelled'.

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't follow you. Perhaps I was not clear enough, the **resource** in the first example is being patched, to have the 'status' field set to 'cancel'. In the second example, the **resource** is being entirely replaced by the string 'cancel'.

Comment: Personally I would use 'state' over 'status' for something like this... but that's a whole different question. But in either case, you wouldn't use a verb as a state, you would use a adjective like 'cancelled'.

Comment: So in OO terms, `order.cancel()`. What happens if cancelling an order takes more then just setting the order's state to 'cancelled'. With your approach you would have to check what field is being modified (in you PUT request) then have a mapping to the corresponding cancel function.

Comment: By extension, what if multiple fields are effected, the user/client should not have to know about this!

Comment: Firstly, do not try to map the HTTP request's directly to function calls, we are talking about REST not RPC. I figured that a user might set the status to 'cancel', and once it is 'cancelled' the status is further updated, but apples and pairs really. Don't forget, if the you GET that order, it should have a field 'status', so it should be reasonable for the user to be able to then PATCH that field (and if we sent them JSON, they should presume the PATCH is via JSON). In the PUT request (which I'm not big a fan off, it's there for completion) the user is accessing a 'status' resource...

Comment: That alone is a bit dodgy. YOu have to think how you are going to link them to that, presumably from the 'order' resource as a whole. And yes, by letting them PATCH the order, they can update all they want. They could add a note too `{'status':'cancel','note':'found it cheaper elsewhere suckas!'}` If you only let the user PUT such data, it has to be done field at a time, which in this example may not be that big a deal.

Comment: Not really apple and pears, but that's beyond the point of this question. You could restrict them to what fields they can PATCH. Yes modifying public fields is all well and good, but if performing an action needs to update private ones (inaccessible to the API) or has to kick off other process for example (email?). This is what encapsulation/methods are for. If you do it via your approach with just patching a single field, you will need to have a mapping to a function, your documentation would will have to say that if you ever modify field X it will do ABC as well. This bad API design.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from rejecting a PATCH, maybe the user doesn't 'own' that resource, maybe the field they are trying to update is read-only, or they set it to an invalid value. All perfectly reasonable reasons to reject the users PATCH. As for wanting to kick off another process, that's fine too. You can happily respond to the user, indicated that something else has been kicked off. It is slow, provide them with a way to get the status, something like `/process_status_reports/3482349/`.

Comment: Sorry thecoshman, but i'm not sure you are following my questions/points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55852/discussion-between-thecoshman-and-metalstorm).